# EclipseLink Sql-Server IDENTITY_INSERT ERROR

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, sql-server-2000, eclipselink

Using EclipseLink, I am trying to insert rows into a SQLServer legacy DB which has an auto-incrementing identity column:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tContacts] (
[conIdContact] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
[conContactName] [varchar] (100) NOT NULL , ...
```

I am using the 'identity" strategy as described in 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Example_identity_XML

```
      <orm:id name="id">
        <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY"/>
        <orm:column name="conIdContact" updatable="false" />
  </orm:id>
```

EclipseLink produces the following SQL:

```
Call: INSERT INTO tContacts (conIdContact, ConContactName, ...
VALUES (?, ?, ...
bind => [null, testheini_2, ...
```

resulting in the following exception:
*Internal Exception:* com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Ein expliziter Wert für die Identitätsspalte kann in der tContacts-Tabelle nicht eingefügt werden, wenn IDENTITY_INSERT auf OFF festgelegt ist.
*Error Code: 544*

(sorry this is german, but it tells us no value can be inserted into the identity column as long as IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF, which is the default)

I assume SQLServer wants to create the ID itself so does not like that EclipseLink tries to insert a value (here: null) into the id-column.
all other strategies, or omitting the generated-value stragegy alltogether, produce the same result.
So far I have found no way to get EclipseLink to insert records into this table!
Setting IDENTITY INSERT to ON is no viable solution, because the standard user should not have the rights to modify the table.
Mapping this table in Hibernate was straightforward, so I am very surprised it seems to be impossible with EclipseLink. Here how I did it in Hibernate:

```
        <id name="id" type="int">
        <column name="conIdContact" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
```

I am stuck and I appreciate any ideas what is going wrong here!
Hannes

@Chris: I persist like that:
            con.setName("testheini_2");
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(con);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
The contact-orm.xml file is used indeed, which I can see as soon as I add a typo.
I also added
    property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="SQLServer"
or
    property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.SQLServerPlatform"
to the persistence.xml, but it does not make any difference. 
What else could I check?
Hannes

Comment: How are you persisting this entity, and are you sure the orm file with the generated-value tag being picked up?  You might check that there are no other older files that might conflict on the path somehow picked up instead, as IDENTITY seems to work in EclipseLink nightly testing, and works eventually in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595432/eclipselink-jpa-gets-error-when-inserting-into-derby-table-with-generated-primar

Comment: @Chris - did you try with annotations or with mapping file like in example? I just verified that IDENTITY works with annotations, but not with mapping file. I guess this is a bug.

Comment: A bug is a great idea if you have a simple test case, but before that, I would turn logging on and check there aren't warning messages being missed that might indicate what is going wrong.

Comment: @Chris, there is one exception on FINER, but it runs on and finally produces the SQL that leads to the error. ([EL Finer]: Could not initialize Validation Factory. Encountered following exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validation
). I think I'll file a bug.